# How can i fix 'Guild' object has no attribute 'text_channel' in discord.py module

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to know how to fix this problem.My original code is this:

```py
import discord

from discord.ext import commands  


intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True,presences=True)


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!dc ", intents=intents)

async def on_ready():  
    print("I am ready!")


####Probably,I am getting this error because of these codes below


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channel,name = "Welcome")
    await channel.send(f"{member} welcome :)")
    

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channel , name="the-ones-who-won't-beforgotten")
    await channel.send(f"{member} left the server :(")

client.run(mytoken)
```

Note:Whenever I tried to run this code,first it worked fine and printed "I am ready!".But,whenever someone left or joined the server,I recieved that error above.Could someone help me?

Comment: I think you're looking for `guild.text_channels`, how a guild is supposed to have a single text channel? doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński What is  guild?This might be awkard but idk that actually.I am new on it

Comment: `guild = member.guild` or use `member.guild.text_channels` altogether

Comment: @hARASİVa a `Guild` is the formal word for a `server`. Also, if you don't know what a Guild is, how are you using it in your code...?

Comment: thank you everyone for your answers,I've solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the `.text_channels` attribute.

```
channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, name = "Welcome")
etc.
```

See Guild object attributes [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild).

See `text_channels` attribute [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.text_channels).